# How to pause an MSI installer and continue it?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

i'm coding in C# and at the moment i'm trying to install a MSI installer via code.
That works fine with MsiInstallProduct. Moreover i've got an InstallUiHandlerRecord callback 
function where i can get infos like progress and so on.

Now i've got a problem: If i use an installer built by WIX or Wise and while installing i click cancel, the installation stops, a message box appears with the question if you really want to cancel and if you do not want to cancel the installation continues.

My question is if it is possible to build this behaviour by code that i can say pause installation and after interaction say continue installing.

Thanks for yor help in advance.

Comment: I think your question relates to the fact that you you are using an external UI handler and you want also to expose a pause or cancel button in that UI so that, if a user clicks it, you can interrupt the progress of the installation. Cancelling in Windows Installer is a bit tricky. Generally you find that once the transaction has started you've missed the boat. This is why authors will use a custom action to send an INSTALLMESSAGE_COMMONDATA message to Windows Installer to disable the cancel button, as it's useless beyond a certain point.